# Having a personal AND school-vended skydrive account with Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-live, onedrive

I'm running into a bit of trouble trying to solve this problem. When I first set up Windows 8, I made my own personal Windows live account - with a sensible user name that I desired and my own personal password.

However, with my University's mailing system, I'm given a vended email address and password. I use this account to store my school related items, and send/receive school related mail. However, I would not want to use this as my personal account (the password is randomly vended, the domain on the email is non-standard, etc.).

If I'm to understand correctly, I *cannot* log into Windows 8 with my personal live account, and then add an account to view my school mail and school skydrive with the built in tools. I can't even set up sky drive to synchronize my school folder with my school sky drive (it auto-signs in to the current logged in user).

Surely Microsoft would consider or think about people in this situation? Many people have personal and work accounts that they would like to remain separate.

Is there anything I can do to remedy this situation? I would like to use the built in mail and sky drive tools to view both of my accounts.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Strange.  I've added two `@Live` accounts, an `@Outlook` account, work Exchange account, and a personal exchange account while signing in with a Microsoft account.  Not sure why it won't let you add more accounts. . .

Comment: "If I'm to understand correctly" ... so did you even try?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this would work for you, but you can [share items in Sky Drive](http://windowslive.ninemsn.com.au/livesuite/article/792828/how-to-guide-sharing-files-with-skydrive). So just log into your school Sky Drive account and Share it with your account that you use in Windows 8. You can grant edit permission when you share.