# Windows 8.1 + Corporate Domain Account + Personal SkyDrive Is it possible?

Tags: windows-8, onedrive

I have on my personal computer windows 8.1, It has 2 accounts one is a personal live account hooked up with windows 8 and skydrive.

The second one is an account through my companies domain. Now I want to add skydrive support to this second account but I want it to be the same one as my personal account.

Is this possible?

Comment: Realted: http://superuser.com/questions/479143/having-a-personal-and-school-vended-skydrive-account-with-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

Each Skydrive account is tied to a single MS account.  You can share files and such with others, and access the SkyDrive.com site from wherever, but not log into the actual SkyDrive account with multiple MS user accounts (especially when dealing with the Windows 8.1 integrated version).

From Windows 8 [SkyDrive: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-8/skydrive-app-faq):

> **Do I have to sign in to my PC with a Microsoft account to use SkyDrive?**
>
> Yes, you need to sign in with a Microsoft account to browse your
>   SkyDrive and keep your files and settings in sync. If you sign in with
>   a local account, you can only use the SkyDrive app to browse your PC.
>   To browse your SkyDrive files, you'll need to go to SkyDrive.com.

and

> **Can I sign in with a different account to browse a different SkyDrive?**
>
> You can't switch between accounts in the SkyDrive app. When you sign
>   in to a PC with your Microsoft account, you're automatically signed in
>   to SkyDrive with that account. You can still get to SkyDrive files for
>   a different account by going to SkyDrive.com.

Comment: hmmm, can I share the entire skydrive easily? Basically merging the too? I think this was very short sighted of MS.

Comment: Not short-sighted, the idea is that the drive is private, except what you decide to share explicitly.  Having multiple people (MS accounts) share a single SkyDrive (account) would make it NOT private. ;)  In most countries, companies have to follow privacy laws set out by the government.

Comment: Well, I think it is short sighted as they did not factor that someone might need to have multiple windows accounts but only need 1 skydrive account. I need to have a work account but my work would not even allow me putting company stuff on a skydrive anyways so I rather just have my personal one hooked up to that account as well as right now.

Comment: If your company doesn't want you using SkyDrive, then you shouldn't use it, unless you like getting fired. ;)  But anyhow, MS did what they did because of how they see things, if you don't like it switch to another product (PS: (AFAIK) you can't have more than one Google account tied to a Google Drive in this manner either).

Comment: As I stated I won't use it for work related stuff but my company I work for does not care if I have a skydrive filled with my data on the computer. Ya you can't have more than one google account on a google drive but when you install it on your computer you can put any account you want it does not matter, I can have 5 different computers all setup with the same google drive account and it will work.

Comment: Yes, and you can log into 5 different Windows 8.1 machines with the same MS account and have the same Skydrive available to you in all those places. Anyhow, we've drifted from the original question.  Perhaps someone will come along with an answer more to your liking, but I'm pretty sure what I've stated is just 'how it is' -- at least currently.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options:

1. If you don't need local file sync, you could just [map a drive](http://www.techattend.com/use-skydrive-with-local-account-windows-8-1/).
2. To sync files the way the standard SkyDrive app does, [syncDriver](http://syncdriver.com/) seems to work (see [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/694623/skydrive-on-windows-8-1?rq=1)).