# SkyDrive on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

Is it possible to use SkyDrive on Windows 8.1 without using a cloud account?

I tried switching to a cloud account but it screwed up authentication between my PCs as they rely on identical user names and passwords on each device.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'cloud' account? It needs a microsoft account logged into it for it to upload the files iirc. I made my microsoft account with my gmail email though.

Comment: A cloud account is an account in the cloud, in this case a Microsoft account. Mine is @hotmail.com.

Comment: So you had the same username on more than 1 PC in the house and they stayed in sync until you switch to a cloud account on one of them?

Comment: Please give more information. Like what do you want to do and whats the problem. If it screwed the authentication why don't you log in in all your PC's with the cloud account ?

Comment: Why the downvote? The question is relevant, clear (it got a a correct answer quickly) and contains all relevant information. (Why I don't want to switch all my PCs to a cloud account is not relevant to the question!)

Comment: Yes, I have the same username and password on all my PCs. I cannot switch all of them to a cloud account for various reasons, among them that I don't want my local user accounts to be controlled by Microsoft and the simple fact that older versions of Windows do not support cloud accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the tool [syncDriver](https://web.archive.org/web/20161125113322/http://syncdriver.com/about) to add SkyDrive to win8.1 when you use a local account:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me.  Says can't connect to Skydrive, but the password is definitely correct. I'm worried this is a phishing attempt

Comment: It is working fine for me. I got synchronized my account. They don't support two phase authentication, it could be the reason of your connection problem.

Comment: SyncDriver is no longer. What now?